# pymongo / mongodb advanced query

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I'm a novice in pymongo/mongodb and now I have a challenge.

I have the following structure stored in mongodb (v 2.04).

```
{
    "t": <timestamp>, 
    "d": {
        "uid": <string>,
        "action": <string>
    }
}
```

This structure tracks user actions and is slightly reduced in complexity from my original.
The data is pretty huge and the query will have a limiting datespan to reduce the results.

What I would like is to be able to create a table of the users who did the most actions during a certain timespan.

Table:

```
Rank    Uid    #num actions
1       5      235
2       237    234
3       574    229
```

So far I've only bits and pieces of the query:

```
query = {"t": {"$lte": end_utc, "$gte": start_utc}}
db.actions.find(query).distinct("d.uid")
```

Which will simply produce a list of unique uid's.
How can I query (using pymongo) to get a list such as:

```
[
    {
        "actions": 100,
        "uid": 273
    },
    {
        "actions": 99",
        "uid": 632
    }..n sorted on actions descending

]
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're using MongoDB 2.1+ you can use the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/) for this type of query:

```py
db.actions.aggregate([
    # Filter the docs to just those within the specified timerange
    {"$match": {"t": {"$lte": end_utc, "$gte": start_utc}}},

    # Group the docs on d.uid, assembling a count of action docs with each value
    {"$group": {"_id": "$d.uid", "actions": {"$sum": 1}}},

    # Sort by actions, descending
    {"$sort": { "actions": -1 }}
])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm running version 2.0.4 so I guess I have to use map reduce. Thinking about upgrading to 2.1.x, but read its unstable...

Comment: @terjeto The odd numbered point releases like 2.1 are unstable development builds, but 2.2.1 is released and stable.  That's the one you want.